# vbScript to Delphi (Error: Type not allowed in Variant Dispatch call)

Tags: delphi, vbscript, callback, com

I am trying to convert VBscript to Delphi but stuck on this line:

```
test.init_library(myObj); //=> Type not allowed in Variant Dispatch call
```

How can I fix the error ?
Would you convert the vbscript code differently ?
Any suggestions are welcome.
Thanks

Some vbscript code I'm trying to convert:

```
Class myClass
  Public user
  public password
End class

dim myObj
Set myObj = New myClass
myObj.user = "userName"
myObj.password = "userPwrd"


set My_obj = wscript.CreateObject("COMtest","pref_")

Set init_lib = My_obj.get_init_library_obj

call init_lib.init_library(GetRef("Library_created"), myObj)

sub Library_created(p_Object)
  result = TypeName( p_Object) 
  MsgBox "class: " + result +" called for user: "+p_Object.user, 0, "COM Test"
end sub
```

Delphi code:

```
procedure Test
var
  myObj : myClass;
  test : variant;
  ComObj : OleVariant;
  begin
    myObj := myClass.Create;
    myObj.user := 'userName';
    myObj.password := 'userPwrd';
    ComObj := CreateOleObject('COMtest');

    //Initialise obj
    test := ComObj.get_init_library_obj;

   test.init_library(myObj); //=> Type not allowed in Variant Dispatch call
end;
```

Comment: You can't pass a Delphi class via COM interop. It's not one of the supported types.

Comment: Yes myObj is the wrong thing. It needs to be the equivalent of wscript.CreateObject("COMtest","pref_")

Comment: Can anyone tell me what's the equivalent of wscript.CreateObject("COMtest","pref_") either in Delphi or C# ?  Thank you.